# PHP Laravel, identify not used translations

Tags: php, laravel, translation

I was thinking if there is a way to identify unused translation keys in laravel using regular underscore translation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*If you are using the translations in loop using some patterns, this won't work and you might end up deleting keys which were in use.*

One of the way would be to use `grep`

First, open tinker

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then require the translation file and store it against a variable

```
$translations = require resource_path('lang/en/app.php');
```

The `$translations` variable would contain the array that is returned by the translation file.

Loop through the array and use `grep` against each key

```
$unused_keys = [];

foreach ($translations as $key => $value) {

    // Here app is the name of the translation file
    // that was required in first step.
    // Replace app with the name of the translation file that is been required.

    $out = exec('echo $(grep -rn "app.' . $key . '" . --exclude-dir=vendor)');

    echo strlen($out) . " " . $key . "\n";

    if (strlen($out) <= 0) {
        $unused_keys[] = $key;
    }
}

// The $unused_keys array would contain the translation key that is not being used.
```

Comment: How do you use these multi lines in Tinker?

Comment: Write the multiline to a php script and execute the respective script in tinker.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/use-tinker-with-code-from-file